# Add column in dataframe from another dataframe matching the id and based on condition in date columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My problem is a very complex and confusing one, I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere.
I basically have 2 dataframes, one is price history of certain products and the other is invoice dataframe that contains transaction data.

Sample Data:

Price History:

```
    product_id    updated  price
id                              
1            1 2022-01-01    5.0
2            2 2022-01-01    5.5
3            3 2022-01-01    5.7
4            1 2022-01-15    6.0
5            2 2022-01-15    6.5
6            3 2022-01-15    6.7
7            1 2022-02-01    7.0
8            2 2022-02-01    7.5
9            3 2022-02-01    7.7
```

Invoice:

```
   transaction_date  product_id  quantity
id                                       
1        2022-01-02           1         2
2        2022-01-02           2         3
3        2022-01-02           3         4
4        2022-01-14           1         1
5        2022-01-14           2         4
6        2022-01-14           3         2
7        2022-01-15           1         3
8        2022-01-15           2         6
9        2022-01-15           3         5
10       2022-01-16           1         3
11       2022-01-16           2         2
12       2022-01-16           3         3
13       2022-02-05           1         1
14       2022-02-05           2         4
15       2022-02-05           3         7
16       2022-05-10           1         4
17       2022-05-10           2         2
18       2022-05-10           3         1
```

What I am looking to achieve is to add the price column in the Invoice dataframe, based on:

1. The product id
2. Comparing the Updated and Transaction Date in a way that updated date <= transaction date for that particular record, basically finding the closest date after the price was updated. (The MAX date that is <= transaction date)

I managed to do this:

```
invoice['price'] = invoice['product_id'].map(price_history.set_index('id')['price'])
```

but need to incorporate the date condition now.

Expected result for sample data:

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOwgO.png)

Any guidance in the correct direction is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Pandas `merge_asof` might be what you are after

Answer (score 1):

[`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) is what you are looking for:

```py
pd.merge_asof(
    invoice,
    price_history,
    left_on="transaction_date",
    right_on="updated",
    by="product_id",
)[["transaction_date", "product_id", "quantity", "price"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

merge_asof with arg direction

```
merged = pd.merge_asof(
    left=invoice,
    right=price_history,
    left_on="transaction_date",
    right_on="updated",
    by="product_id",
    direction="backward",
    suffixes=("", "_y")
).drop(columns=["id_y", "updated"]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(merged)


    id transaction_date  product_id  quantity  price
0    1       2022-01-02           1         2    5.0
1    2       2022-01-02           2         3    5.5
2    3       2022-01-02           3         4    5.7
3    4       2022-01-14           1         1    5.0
4    5       2022-01-14           2         4    5.5
5    6       2022-01-14           3         2    5.7
6    7       2022-01-15           1         3    6.0
7    8       2022-01-15           2         6    6.5
8    9       2022-01-15           3         5    6.7
9   10       2022-01-16           1         3    6.0
10  11       2022-01-16           2         2    6.5
11  12       2022-01-16           3         3    6.7
12  13       2022-02-05           1         1    7.0
13  14       2022-02-05           2         4    7.5
14  15       2022-02-05           3         7    7.7
15  16       2022-05-10           1         4    7.0
16  17       2022-05-10           2         2    7.5
17  18       2022-05-10           3         1    7.7
```